# Hello world exit code

Tags: exit-code

I just compiled my hello world c program  with gcc and ran it in ubuntu. Since I ran it through emacs, I got the exit code of the program: 13. Why 13? I didn't specify anything, so why didn't it default to 0? When I put an exit function at the end, I could change it, but I'm wondering what the significance of this default is.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: care to post your code so we can actually help you ;)

Comment: Your function declaration says it will return `int`, but you have no `return` statement. Therefore, what it returns is random. If you expect it to return zero when there is no error, return zero. Where in the C language definition do you see that the default return value from a function that doesn't return a value will be zero?

Comment: You need to include `return 0;` at the end of `main`. Also, `main` should be declared as `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Comment: The standards (both C and C++) require this program to exit by passing 0 to `exit`, which produces a success process status, which in Unix-land is represented by process exit code 0. So if you don't see 0, and your checking of the exit code is correct, then you have compiler bug. Please do show the build command, the run command and the exit code checking and its result.

Comment: @reirab: no, that's all incorrect.

Comment: @KenWhite: no, that's incorrect.

Comment: @reirab: I believe the correct declaration would be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, unless things have changed and no none told me. :-)

Comment: also I tried searching for any special reason for '13' as error code , there wasn't any but I found this : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, that's right. I meant the parameter list. You're correct about the return type, though. Fixed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: OK, things changed since I last regularly used C. It's still a poor idea to depend on a return value without setting a return value, IMO. If you expect a non-error return of zero, return a zero when your code reaches the end without error. The declaration says it will return `int`, and therefore there should be a return statement that returns an `int` value. Failing to do so violates the function declaration.

Comment: Why 13?  `printf()` returns the number of characters printed.  "Hello, world!" is 13 characters long.  So I guess that without an explicit `return` or `exit()`, `main()` is returning the value of the last expression.

Comment: @JimLewis Which makes sense considering that compilers often put the return value in a reg. Since you haven't explicitly changed the value of that reg with a `return` statement (or any other statement) it still has the value set by the previous return statement.

Comment: When I changed it to `void main(int argc, char *argv[])`, I still get 13

Comment: @RenéG That's because main isn't actually void. Adding the `return 0;` should fix it. Alternatively, you could tell the compiler to use a newer version of the C standard, as mentioned in paxdiablo's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of C99, reaching the end of `main` without a return is the same as if you'd returned zero (only `main`, not all functions in general). Before C99 (and I believe `gcc` defaults to C89/90 as a baseline), it was not defined what would happen, so you should be explicitly returning zero if that's what you need.

Or you could adopt C99/C11 by compiling with `-std=c99` or the `c11` one.

In terms of why 13, it's neither relevant nor portable but it's likely that the return code is whatever happens to be in the eax register (or equivalent if you're using a different calling convention or architecture). For x86, that would probably still be the value that was returned from `printf`, which returns the number of characters printed.

Answer (score -3):

Either you can use void main() instead of int main() so you don't have to give any return type but if you use int main, then you have to provide the return statement

Comment: **–1** "you can use void main()" is incorrect. "you have to provide the return statement" is incorrect.